# strange behavior when trying to read a file

Tags: c, file

```
if(argc==1){    
    } else if(argc==2){
        FILE *f=fopen( argv[1],"r");

        if(!(f==NULL)){
            jogada='x';
            while(countblank(board)!=0 || (checkmoves(board,jogada)>0)){
                fscanf(f,"%d%c",&fline,&fcol_char);
                fcol=fcol_char-'A';
                fline--;

                play(board,fline,fcol,jogada);
                jogada=opcolor(jogada);
                if(fgetc(f)==EOF){
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(f);
            print_board(board);
        }
        else{
        printf("\nFicheiro não foi lido\n");
        }
    }
```

I use gcc and when I do `./othello_func jogadas.txt` it is supposed to read the plays in the file `jogadas.txt` that has something like

```
4C
3E
```

but when I do `./othello_func jogadas.txt` it just shows me the message from the else.

Comment: By "the message from else" do you mean `"\nFicheiro não foi lido\n"`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is it unable to locate the file or is it unable to parse the correct file?

Comment: i don t know it just realy don't pass the if(!(f==NULL)) and just retrive me the printf of the else part

Comment: @L1nK Does the file really exist where you think it does? Is it in the same directory as `othello_func`?

Comment: yeah it exist i can go and open it and show me the plays i have saved inside but i don't know if i need to compile it or something like that

Comment: More exactly is the `jogadas.txt` file in whatever the current directory is? When you use an IDE, the current directory is often not what you would expect...

Comment: both files are in the same folder

Comment: Run `perror()` in the else block.

Comment: it says ```No such file or directory``` but i have the file and i can open it

Comment: It's a pretty clear error message.

Comment: You are not executing the program in the correct location, navigate to the folder where the executable is located, if it indeed is created.

Comment: What is the gcc command you are using?

Comment: @L1nK It sounds like your [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is not what you think it is. You may want to look at [`man 3 getcwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) and its associated pages.

Comment: i was compiling in the folder p1 and the files are at p1/projeto/othello_func.c now is not showing the else but instead is giving me numbers instead of doing the functions

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problems are, you need to describe the problem in a manner we can reproduce, there are some good programmers here, but none of them has divinatory skills, to my knowledge. Maybe you should take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I do ./othello_func jogadas.txt it just shows me the message from the else.

- The program "othello_func" and "jogadas.txt" are not in the same folder.  [OP reports they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581760/strange-behavior-when-trying-to-read-a-file/70582723#comment124770508_70581760) but may be mistaken about which folder code is run from.

OR

- The file "jogadas.txt" is not available for reading - perhaps being used by another program like an editor.